# Can Bootstrap's Tooltip be made to support both HTML and non-HTML titles?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

Bootstrap's Tooltip in general works via the `title` and `data-title` attributes of the element. I can specify HTML code via the `data-html="true"` attribute, so for example

```html
<a href="..." data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="<b>First Line:</b><br>Second Line.">...</a>
```

Which renders fine via the Tooltip plugin:

[image: element tooltip with JS enabled]

But the problem arises when JavaScript is disabled; in this case the browser shows the raw value of the `title` attribute and in essence the raw HTML, which to the end user looks quite bad:

[image: element title with JS disabled]

Is there a way to implement graceful degradation for tooltips containing HTML? Such that an HTML-containing value will be used by the plugin, but simple, clear-text value used by default by the browser (when Bootstrap tooltips are not enabled or when JS is not enabled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing a custom transformation before enabling the Bootstrap's tooltips. The transformation removes the `title` attribute from the target element and leaves only the "rich" `data-title` attribute. When JS is disabled, this code will have no effect, the `data-title` attribute will have no effect, and the browser will pick the plain-text `title` attribute up.

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"][title][data-title]').each(function() {
    this.setAttribute('data-simple-title', this.getAttribute('title'));
    this.removeAttribute('title');
});
$(document).tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]' });
```